Azure automation failed when starting stream analytics
I have set up an automation app to stop and start a stream analytics job, following a guide from this doc
I have tried the code, yet it is struggling to pull a value from the stopped log in azure stream analytics, it just returns a null value for the timestamp.
CODE EXCERPT:
$startTimeStamp = Get-AzActivityLog -ResourceId $resourceId -MaxRecord 1000 -WarningAction Ignore | Where-Object {$_.EventName.Value -like "Start Job*"}
$startTimeStamp = $startTimeStamp | Select-Object -First 1 | Foreach-Object {$_.EventTimeStamp}

ERROR EXCERPT:
"Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2". (Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".)".
Am using PowerShell 7.2.
Any help would be appreciated. @Florian
Here is the link to the code

 if ($currentJobState -eq "Running")
    { 
        # Get-AzActivityLog issues warnings about deprecation coming in future releases, here we ignore them via -WarningAction Ignore
        # We check in 1000 record of history, to make sure we're not missing what we're looking for. It may need adjustment for a job that has a lot of logging happening.
        # There is a bug in Get-AzActivityLog that triggers an error when Select-Object First is in the same pipeline (on the same line). We move it down.
        $startTimeStamp = Get-AzActivityLog -ResourceId $resourceId -MaxRecord 1000 -WarningAction Ignore | Where-Object {$_.EventName.Value -like "Start Job*"}
        $startTimeStamp = $startTimeStamp | Select-Object -First 1 | Foreach-Object {$_.EventTimeStamp}

        # Get-AzMetric issues warnings about deprecation coming in future releases, here we ignore them via -WarningAction Ignore
        $currentBacklog = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $resourceId -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -MetricName "InputEventsSourcesBacklogged" -DetailedOutput -WarningAction Ignore
        $currentWatermark = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $resourceId -TimeGrain 00:01:00 -MetricName "OutputWatermarkDelaySeconds" -DetailedOutput -WarningAction Ignore

        # Metric are always lagging 1-3 minutes behind, so grabbing the last N minutes means checking N+3 actually. This may be overly safe and fined tune down per job.
        $Backlog =  $currentBacklog.Data | `
                        Where-Object {$_.Maximum -ge 0} | `
                        Sort-Object -Property Timestamp -Descending | `
                        Where-Object {$_.Timestamp -ge $startTimeStamp} | `
                        Select-Object -First $stopThresholdMinute | 
                        Measure-Object -Sum Maximum
        $BacklogSum = $Backlog.Sum

        $Watermark = $currentWatermark.Data | `
                        Where-Object {$_.Maximum -ge 0} | `
                        Sort-Object -Property Timestamp -Descending | `
                        Where-Object {$_.Timestamp -ge $startTimeStamp} | `
                        Select-Object -First $stopThresholdMinute | `
                        Measure-Object -Average Maximum
        $WatermarkAvg = [int]$Watermark.Average

        Write-Output "asaRobotPause - Job $($asaJobName) is running since $($startTimeStamp) with a sum of $($BacklogSum) backlogged events, and an average watermark of $($WatermarkAvg) sec, for $($Watermark.Count) minutes."



Have tried all in the guide, and have gotten the program to work to stop the stream. Cannot get it to work when starting the stream.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Will Mclennan # Get-Date returns a local time, we project it to the same time zone (universal) as the result of Get-AzActivityLog that we extracted above
$minutesSinceStopped = ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()- $stopTimeStamp).TotalMinutes

@Will Mclennan Write-Output "Stop Time Stamp: $stopTimeStamp"
